# Display mandatory data on form ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a list of mandatory data about app users, which are all users must to have. I need one button, and on click event, I want to show all mandatory data which are null in database.
Note: list of mandatory data has about 30 fields, and these fields are in 5+ sql tables...
It's ASP.NET app with MS SQL Server database...
Any idea how to implement this functionality?

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/learnmore/Validation.asp

Answer (score 0):

The fastest technology that will get you there is ASP.NET Dynamic Data, BUT you will have some work to do. BTW - you do not need MVC to use Dynamic Data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452.aspx and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488545.aspx

In your case, you say that you want to *require* entry for fields which are null in the database. This is a little unusual. Normally, we require entry for fields which represent non-nullable columns, so that we will never attempt to put a null into the database. In your case, you will have manually apply UIHints that indicate that the field is required.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488532.aspx

Dynamic Data will take a little experimentation if it's your first time. Also, it presents your tables and fields in a default way, so if you want to modify the presentation, you will have some customization work to do. The MSDN documentation should have most of what you need.

Comment: I'm so far from dynamic data :-) I need a solution in .NET 2.0.

Comment: Bummer. I don't know an EASY way to do this. You'll just have to add RequiredFieldValidator controls all over your page, and then selectively enable or disable those controls when you do your initial DataBind, based on the IsXXXXNull property from your DataRows (assuming you're using ADO.NET). But the RequiredFieldValidators will all be invoked with the one-button click on submit.

Comment: I decided to create one sproc with the all mandatory fields like output parameters. This sproc will return 0 for mandatory fields that haven't value or 1 for fields that have a value. The question is, how to work with this stored procedure in application? The task is to display message if user has all mandatory fields, and show pop up if user hasn't mandatory fields, and then to display a list of these fields...

Comment: I don't know why you needed the stored procedure. ADO.NET supports nullable columns, and you just use the boolean `Is<Field>Null` property of the DataRow to determine whether the field is null or not. THat's the same as your 0 and 1 values from your sproc, but doesn't require another trip to the database (which, besides being very inefficient, is more complex than you need). In your page's DataBind method, check all of the `Is<Field>Null` property, then enable the corresponding `RequiredFieldValidator` control if its true, and disable it if it's false.

Comment: Tnx, for the suggestion. Correct me if I'm wrong.But, on that way, I can validate only each user control separately?

Comment: Separately? Do you mean you think you can only enable one at a time per postback? No, you can enable multiple `RequiredFieldValidator` at a time, but you will need one validator per control. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. I thought you were just trying to get the user to update a record that has missing data by requiring the user to enter the missing data. That's exactly what a `RequiredFieldValidator` will do. You can also use a `SummaryValidator` control to display the messages from all of the `RequiredFieldValidator`s in one place on your page.